# Display offline users in twitch tv javascript

Tags: javascript, json, twitch

I want to be able to display Twitchtv offline users with their logos.

I was able to get the infos regards online users, however I am still struggling to get the offline users to display properly. Any suggestions ???

$(document).ready(function() {

var twitchAPI = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/";

```
 var users = [
'justin', 
'syndicate', 
'riotgames', 
'captainsparklez', 
'LIRIK', 
'PhantomL0rd', 
'esl_csgo', 
'sodapoppin',
'summit1g',
'Nightblue3',
'goldglove',
'tsm_bjergsen',
'imaqtpie',
'tsm_theoddone',
'trick2g'
```

];

```
var index, len;

for (index = 0, len = users.length; index < len; ++index) {

$.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + users[index], function(channels) {

  if (channels["stream"] != null) {

    $("#showOnline").append('<div>' + "&#160; " + channels.stream.channel.name + "&#160; &#160;" + ("<img src= '" +    channels.stream.channel.logo + "'>") + '</div>');

    $("#showOnline").css({color: 'green'}); //color green undicates ONLINE status

     }

   });

}


});
```

Answer (score 0):

The Api which you are using to retrieve the logo could be replaced with `"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/"` because the api which you are using doesn't have the link to the logo.

The above api return the JSON which consist of link to the logo of the streamer incase the streamer is offline.